# elasticsearch geo search with multiple must

Tags: php, json, curl, elasticsearch, match

I am using elasticsearch with bool/must/filter and in filter using the `geo_distance` filter. Here are some sample queries:

#### Example 1:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/indexname/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
```

---

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must": {
        "term": { "name": "cafe" }
      },        
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance" : {
          "distance" : "20km",
          "pin.coordinates" : {
            "lat" : 13.9291040000,
            "lon" : -70.8269250000
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

For the above query, I'm getting atleast 1 or more results.

#### Example 2:

If I use `should` along with the above query it is not displaying any hits/results

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/indexname/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
```

---

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must": {
        "term": { "name": "cafe" }
      },        
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance" : {
          "distance" : "20km",
          "pin.coordinates" : {
            "lat" : 13.9291040000,
            "lon" : -70.8269250000
          }
        }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "category_ol" : "cafe" } },
        { "term" : { "name_en" : "cafe" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
      "boost" : 1.0   
    }
  }
}
```

Any solution please?

TIA

Comment: what is your query exactly, can you put a SQL pseudo query.

Comment: this query to get all points within a 'radius' around 'lat-lng'

SELECT
    *,
    ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians({$lat}) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lng` ) - radians({$lng}) ) + sin( radians({$lat}) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM `tablename`
HAVING distance <= {$radius}
ORDER BY distance ASC

something like this to get the local search result from nearest to farthest